# How to update the exact row in table using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, row

My view page:
[image]

In this picture i am getting data like `loan no`, `partyname`, `coll.amt` using `date` (ie it display the data in that particular date when i gave, from "collection" table)

If i have entered the rep amt  for `loan no` 2 but i didn't give to `loan no` 1, 3. when i pressed `ok button` the rep amt should be updated in that "collecion" table for exact loan number and date.

My Model code:

```php
public function batchinsert($data){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['repname'];
    $LDate = $this->input->post('CDate');
    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $LDate);
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    $lno = $this->input->post("Sno");
    $count = count($data['Sno']);
    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){ 
        $entries2[] = array(               
            'receive_amt'=>$data['ramt'][$i],

            ); 
    }
    $this->db->where('loanno',$lno);
    $this->db->where('collection_date',$newDate);
    $this->db->update_batch('collection',$entries2);
    //        $this->db->insert_batch('test', $entries2);
    redirect('Collection_Entry','refresh');
}
```

My Controller code:

```php
public function Collection_Insert(){
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $result = $this->User_model->batchinsert($_POST);
}
```

My View page Code:

```php
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Loan No</th>
            <th>Party Name</th>
            <th>Coll.Amt</th>
            <th>Rep Amt</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($result2);exit();
    if(!empty($query)){
        foreach($query as $row){
    ?>
        <tr >
        <td ><input style="width:50px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="Sno[]" id="Sno" value="<?=$row['loanno'];?>"></td>

        <td> <input style="width:180px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="name[]" id="Amount" value="<?=$row['pname'];?>"></td>

        <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs amt" name="Amount[]" id="Bankname" value="<?=$row['collection_amt'];?>"></td>

        <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs ramt" name="ramt[]" id="Chqamt" value="<?=$row['receive_amt'];?>" autofocus></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
        }
    }?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

please solve this problem.

Comment: Could you post your form view? and also where did you get those `$data` variables from?

Comment: For identifying your specific row you need to give different class for different inputs.

Comment: @ArifulIslam please see my code i have edited then clear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make updates only on `ramt[]` input that having non-empty value, you could assign a key to each of the input text name to identify it later :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb3">
    <thead>
            <tr>
    <th>Loan No</th>
    <th>Party Name</th>
    <th>Coll.Amt</th>
    <th>Rep Amt</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($result2);exit();
        if(!empty($query)){
            foreach($query as $key => $row){ // added $key as index
            ?>
                <tr >
                    <td ><input style="width:50px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="Sno[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Sno" value="<?=$row['loanno'];?>"></td>

                    <td> <input style="width:180px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="name[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Amount" value="<?=$row['pname'];?>"></td>

                    <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs amt" name="Amount[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Bankname" value="<?=$row['collection_amt'];?>"></td>

                    <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs ramt" name="ramt[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Chqamt" value="<?=$row['receive_amt'];?>" autofocus></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
        }?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And filter the input data on your `batchinsert()` function :

```
public function batchinsert($data){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['repname'];
    $LDate = $this->input->post('CDate');
    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $LDate);
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    $lno = $this->input->post("Sno");
    $ramt = $this->input->post("ramt"); // added ramt input variable
    $count = count($data['Sno']);
    $updateArray = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($lno); $x++){

        if (!empty($ramt[$x])) { // this will only insert data on loanno which have non-empty ramt values
            $updateArray[] = array(
                'loanno' => $lno[$x],
                'receive_amt'=> $ramt[$x]
            );
        }
    }
    $this->db->where('collection_date',$newDate);
    $this->db->update_batch('collection',$updateArray,'loanno');
    //        $this->db->insert_batch('test', $entries2);
    redirect('Collection_Entry','refresh');
}
```

This will only loops through non-empty `ramt[]` input then only updates on dynamic `loanno` values and a static `collection_date` value.

```
// Example query output : 
// UPDATE `collection`
// SET
// `receive_amt` = 
// CASE 
//     WHEN `loanno` = '1' THEN 1 
//     WHEN `loanno` = '3' THEN 2 
//     WHEN `loanno` = '6' THEN 3 
//     WHEN `loanno` = '17' THEN 4 
//     ELSE `receive_amt`
// END 
// WHERE `collection_date` = '2019/01/09' AND `loanno` IN ('1','3','6','17')
```

Comment: It shows an error in this line    $this->db->update_batch('collection',$updateArray,'loanno');
  as  Undefined index: loanno

Comment: I have printed and see the value it is correct in your code but this line "$this->db->update_batch('collection',$updateArray,'loanno');" shows an error  and it doesn't update the value

Comment: may I know what CI version are you using?

Comment: 2.1 version may be version problem is not coming,i also thought like this only due version problem

Comment: I believe this `undefined index` on  `update_batch` is a [known bug](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4892) on CI version 3.1.1 / 3.1.2, I'm testing it on CI version 3.1.5 and it's working fine, I don't know with CI version 2.1 though...

Comment: You could also use a standard update (within a loop) instead of an `update_batch` if you want

Comment: your code is correct and i have checked through may website too may be my version is problem i am changing to latest version and trying your  code

Comment: i modified the DB_query_builder. and now i got correct result

Comment: we can able save html table content using this code